# Не удается загрузить appbundle и apk в google console (Flutter)

Tags: flutter

Выскакивает ошибка "Загруженный APK-файл или набор Android App Bundle был подписан в режиме отладки. Подпишите файл или набор в режиме выпуска. Подробнее nullо подписании приложенийnull…", хотя все делаю по инструкции, как написано на официальном сайте Flutter. androidManifest настроил и build.gradle тоже, как написано на сайте, приложение тоже подписал.

Comment: какая IDE используется? Если андроид студио, могу описать пошагово.

Comment: `хотя все делаю по инструкции`, плохо делаете... [Подписать забыли](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app)